# Exporting from blade view to Excel with font size and styling

Tags: excel, laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I'm Using Maatwebsite/Excel to export my Blade view to excel but when I'm exporting  it to excel the font size won't take effect and it won't bring it on center.

If it's not possible in maatwebiste/excel is there any other reporting service like RDLC reporting for laravel

My view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>asdf</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="12" align="center" style="text-align: 
center;font-size:50pt">Should be large and in center</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
    <td>quantity</td>
    <td>units_id</td>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>requster</td>
    <td>checker</td>
    <td>approver</td>
    <td>created_at</td>
    <td>updated_at</td>
    <td>remarks</td>
    <td>request_number</td>
    <td>steps</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach($posts as $post)
 <tr>
    <td>{{$post->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->units_id}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->description}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->requster}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->checker}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->approver}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->remarks}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->request_number}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->steps}}</td>
</tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller

```
    public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'posts.xlsx');
}
```

And my Export Controller

```
class UsersExport implements FromView
{
public function view(): View
{
    return view('exporting', [
        'posts' => Procurment_request::all()
    ]);
}
}
```

My View
[image]

My Exported Excel file
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure it your self.

Take a look at the documentation on how to [format Columns](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html).

```
class InvoicesExport implements WithColumnFormatting, WithMapping
    {
        public function map($invoice): array
        {
            return [
               $invoice->invoice_number,
               Date::dateTimeToExcel($invoice->created_at),
               $invoice->total
            ];
         }

    /**
    * @return array
    */
    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE,
        ];
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm Exporting view to excel it shows array will it work?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to say? I don't understand the question.

Comment: In short I want my Merge cell to be in center of the cell